External Identities - Customize Verification Code mail on signup
I'm playing around with Entra External Identities and creating a simple sign in / sign up flow.
I'd like tu customize the account verification code mail HTML template. Is there any way to do that ?
I've tried looking in the External ID documentation and searching through Azure but could not find anything.
Here's the one from the Woodgrove sample app so people know about which mail i'm talking about :
Woodgrove grocery mail template html
Thanks for any answers.

According to Microsoft, this feature is unavailable but should be available "soon".
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/1697513/entra-id-external-identities-verification-code-mai

You may be able to do something with the branding (much like B2C), but you can change the tenant's name.
"The new tenant name also appears in the verification email sent to the user."

Thanks for the answer. If I follow you correctly, nothing "out-of-the-box" exist to change the mail template ? Will I need to plug some custom business logic in and handle the OTP myself ?

No, nothing OOTB. There is limited plug-in functionality - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/entra/external-id/customers/concept-custom-extensions

Alright, thank you very much. Microsoft confirmed to me in learn.microsoft.com that they're working on that and EEID will be updated "soon". I'll edit the question.
